# Document alternative request bodies

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

The API we are building allows the user to provide different request bodies. From what I have seen / found so far, it is only possible to provide a single request per action/resource. Is it somehow possible to specify different request bodies?

I tried it like:

```
### Create new line item for an existing order [POST]

Some description

+ Request (application/json)

### Create new line item and order [POST]

Some other description

+ Request (application/json)
```

And also like:

```
### Create new line item for an existing order [POST]

Some description

+ Request (application/json)
+ Request (application/json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple request and responses in a single action. Please see the example below.

```
### Create new line item for an existing order [POST]

Some description

+ Request (application/json)
+ Response 200

+ Request (application/json)
+ Response 404

+ Request (application/xml)
+ Request (application/json)
+ Response 200
```